# Summing a List of Values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I can easily sum a comma-separated list of values with a formula like:

```
=SUM(11,13,17,23)
```

I want to do the same thing with the list in a separate cell, so if **A1** contains:

```
11,13,17,23
```

I would like a single cell formula to return ***64***

Neither `=SUM(A1)` nor `=SUM(INDIRECT(A1))` work:

[image]

I can get an answer by using either **TextToColumns** or the *UDF()*:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function zum(SIN As String) As Variant
    Dim ary, a
    ary = Split(SIN, ",")

    For Each a In ary
        zum = zum + Val(a)
    Next a
End Function
```

But I would rather use a single cell formula than *VBA*.

Comment: Can we assume that the list in A1 is arbitrary length rather than all cases having four values?

Comment: Can we also assume that the numbers can be greater than 99 (i.e. not just two digits)? I'm thinking that some combination of the MID, RIGHT, and LEFT functions might work.

Comment: If your question is: can a collection of arguments be specified externally as a string and interpreted as individual arguments, the answer is no. The only way Excel will interpret a delimited collection of values as individual arguments is if they are directly inside the function as an argument list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a helper cell where you write the formula in B1 for example

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","+")`
Then Define Name  `Result`
 and in Refers to write   `=Evaluate(B1)`
and where you want the Sum write =Result

Comment: I am shocked!! ................the Jurassic ***=Evaluate*** function is STILL lurking around!

Comment: I am marking this as **ANSWERED** since only a single helper cell is required and the trick can be copied down a column

Comment: You can try to combine in Refers to  =Evaluate(Substitute(A1,",","+")) in the Define Name

Comment: You are correct! .................the helper cell can be avoided!

Comment: Very clever workaround. +1